# Correlated subqueries with inline view as outer query

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

Is it possible to correlate subquery with an inline view?

Suppose we have simple database that stores information about pet owners.

```
SELECT p.name,  
       p.surname, 
       p.num_of_pets 
  FROM (SELECT person.id_person id_person, 
               person.name      name, 
               person.surname   surname, 
               COUNT(DISTINCT person_pets.id_pet) num_of_pets
          FROM person 
               LEFT JOIN person_pets 
                      ON person.id_person=person_pets.id_person) p 
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM person p1
                WHERE p1.father=p.id_person 
                   OR p1.mother=p.id_person
                  AND p.num_of_pets > 2)
```

I know it's quite strange example, but only wanted to show what I mean. 
When I run such query I get `table or view does not exist` in the place of p table occurrence in subquery. 
I suppose I misunderstand how inline views are processed. 
Are there any limitations in usage compared to views created with 'with' or 'create view' or to existing tables?

Comment: [Yes you can.](http://rextester.com/LQZT12754) . About the error. Check the spelling of table names and add `group by` clause to the inline view.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you intend this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.surname, p.num_of_pets 
FROM (SELECT p.id_person, p.name, p.surname, 
             COUNT(pp.id_person) as num_of_pets
      FROM person p LEFT JOIN
           person_pets pp
           ON p.id_person = pp.id_person
      GROUP BY p.id_person, p.name
     ) p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM person p1
              WHERE (p1.father = p.id_person OR p1.mother = p.id_person) AND
                    p.num_of_pets > 2
             );
```

I'm not sure why you are getting that particular error, but some notes:

- The subquery needs a `GROUP BY` to be syntactically correct.  The `COUNT()` without a `GROUP BY` should result in an error.
- You shouldn't need `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  It has additional overhead, so it is best to get around it.
- The logic in the outer query probably needs parentheses (unless you want fathers with no pets).
- I have a strong preference for using table aliases.